# How to Embed call Viber on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, viber

I have an idea to make call by viber in a website.
Example, when you go to my website by smartphone, you want to contact me, and we are also use Viber. You can click on "Call viber" button to make a call. It's look like "ymsgr:sendim?your_yahoo_id"
I don't know how to do it, is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App call app viber via url cheme on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541805/app-call-app-viber-via-url-cheme-on-ios)