# HTML Viber link to specific number

Tags: html, hyperlink, chat, viber

I need help to implement Viber number in my application. It should connect user directly with Viber chat option and it should add specific number where message need to be send. Is it possible to do this through HTML? What could be other way?

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541805/app-call-app-viber-via-url-cheme-on-ios

Comment: Possible now (2017 year) https://stackoverflow.com/a/43030670/4036664

Answer (score 29):

To open viber chat with a user:

```
<a href="viber://chat/?number=%2BPHONENUMBERWITHCOUNTRYCODE">Viber Chat</a>
```

*IMPORTANT! the number should be with "**%2B**" instead of "**+**".

You can also open Viber contact, so a user will be able to choose call or chat.

**EDIT:** Looks like **contact** link stopped working on February 2019. Chat link still works

```
<a href="viber://contact?number=%2BPHONENUMBERWITHCOUNTRYCODE">Viber Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can add number:

```
<a href="viber://add?number=12345678">Viber</a>
```

or you can chat to:

```
<a href="viber://chat?number=12345678">Viber</a>
```

or you can send message to channel:

```
<a href="viber://pa?chatURI=[public account URI]&text=[message text]"> some text </a>
```