# Start a Viber chat when users click a link

Tags: html, hyperlink, uri, chat, viber

I am trying to find a way to start a viber chat when a user clicks on a link like `<a href="...">Start a viber chat with us</a>` but I had no luck so far finding the correct URI to do this. I know for example that I can use `skype://username?call` or `skype://username?chat` to initiate a call or chat with Skype. How can I do the same thing with Viber?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible.
Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541805/app-call-app-viber-via-url-cheme-on-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, there is a solution to it.
You can use the `viber://chat?number=1234567894` pattern.

Comment: Could you provide some details? How did you find the solution?