# How to access viber and whatsapp programmatically in ios?

Tags: ios, whatsapp, viber

I know how can I make a call and a chat using skype in iOS. Now I want to make a call using viber and whatsapp also I need to open given user's chat box programmatically within my iOS app. I searched a lot and I couldnt find about viber and whatsapp chat and call making.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom URL Scheme for whatsapp is **whatsapp://**

```
    NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Vignesh%2C%20Kumar!"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    }
```

refer : https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Viber

[Launching Viber app via URL scheme on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541805/app-call-app-viber-via-url-cheme-on-ios)