# Programmatically making viber whatsapp call in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, whatsapp, viber

How can I make whatsapp and viber call within my app? I used `viber://calls`and `whatsapp://app` urls within my app. but they are just opening the application.

Comment: No you can't make a call by Custom URL Scheme WhatsApp only allow to open WhatsApp Messenger application, New chat composer, and open WhatsApp with  pre-filled into message text input field on a conversation screen.
https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: @NikhleshBagdiya thanks. How about viber calls? This viber url also just opens the app's recent call view. Can't we make a call for a given number once we tap a button within our application?

Comment: For viber you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541805/launching-viber-app-via-url-scheme-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Whatsapp does not have a URLScheme for direct calling. They only have URL schemes for chat.

May be in the future they might add it. Keep checking the WhatsApp FAQ section.