# How to link viber user page in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

I created a link to connect the viber in wordpress. But it does not working.

```
<a href="href='//chat?number=xxxxxxxxxx'"/>xxxxxxxxxx</a>
```

Comment: link should be `<a href="viber://chat?number=012345678901"">chat</a>`

Comment: But it still not link to the page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541805/launching-viber-app-via-url-scheme-on-ios/43030670#43030670 read this

Answer (score 0):

In your theme functions.php (preferable child theme) use this to allow "viber" protocol:

```
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', function ( $protocols ) {
   $protocols[] = 'viber';
   return $protocols;
} );
```